# Sound issue with Banshee, Rhythmbox

Tags: music, banshee

I have a sound output problem whenever I play files in Rhythmbox, and it's the same in Banshee. Basically, although the files play fine, if I want to fast forward I get this annoying squeaky sound, in other words the transition is not smooth. Strangely enough, if I play the same files in VLC and I fast forward, I don't get that behavior and the transition is very smooth. Is it a codec issue? How can this be fixed? Any ideas anyone?

Best regards.

Comment: It's probably a codec issue.  Banshee and Rhythmbox (and Totem) use gstreamer, but VLC packages its own codecs.  Can you check in the Synaptic Package Manager to see which version of gstreamer and various gstreamer plugins you have? And which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You might consider trying the [Fluendo Playback Pack](http://www.fluendo.com/shop/product/complete-set-of-playback-plugins/).  It's not free software, but as far as gstreamer apps go (Banshee, Rhythmbox, Totem, et al.), it's hard to beat the Fluendo codec support.  The phrase "Just Works" comes to mind.  Good luck!

If you are on Maverick (10.10) or above, it's also available for purchase in the Ubuntu Software Center.

NOTE:  as other commenters have mentioned, the Fluendo mp3 codec is free and also in the Software Center.  The Playback Pack is better advice for a video problem than a sound/mp3 problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to buy anything to have sound playing alright in your computer. At least I have never needed to.

But yes, I think we are looking at a problem with gstreamer. You should report a bug in the [Gnome Bugzilla](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=gstreamer).

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to play MP3's the Fluendo codec for MP3 is free.
It is the other codecs they charge for.
So simply search for MP3 in the software centre install and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I added all the fluendo codecs. Now I have tried banshee and rythmbox, the problem seems to have persisted although the sound produced when I fast forward isn't as annoying as it was. 
I am using Ubuntu 10 LTS, gstreamer 0.10 ffmpeg 0.10-10-1, gstreamer 0.10-pitfdll 0.9.1.1 cvs200802 and gstreamer 0.10 fluendo-mp3 0.10.12.debian 2

Does it make sense? Am I the only one who has a similar issue?

Anyway, I guess VLC excellent reputation is well reserved. I have used on Windows, Linux and Mac, and have very few issues with it.

Regards.